# Cannot import lxml in python:3.4 docker container

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, lxml

Most probably due to resource constraints, I am unable to pip install (and hence build) lxml within a python:3.4 based docker container.

I'm therefore installing the package instead. My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.4
COPY ./ /source
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3-lxml
RUN pip install -r /source/requirements.txt
```

Unfortunately, I am unable to `import lxml`, even when simply running Python in my container, like so:

```
***@*****:/web/source# docker exec -i -t 84c4cbf09321 python
Python 3.4.3 (default, May 26 2015, 19:20:24)
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lxml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'lxml'
>>>
```

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using the `python` image, which installs Python *from source* into `/usr/local`.  You are then trying to install the `lxml` module using the system package manager, `apt-get`.  This installs `lxml` where it will be visible to the *system* Python in `/usr/bin/`, but *not* to the source-installed Python in `/usr/local`.  You have a few choices:

- Don't try to mix the Python package manager (`pip`) with the system package manager.  Just `pip install` everything. I've tried, and much to my surprise I can successfully `pip install lxml` (I wasn't expecting all the build dependencies to be in place but apparently they are).
- Don't bother using the `python` image.  Just start with your favorite distribution (Fedora, Ubuntu, whatever) and use the system package manager:

  ```
  FROM ubuntu
  RUN apt-get install -y python3-lxml
  ```

  With recent Ubuntu images this will get you Python 3.4.2 (NB: called `python3`), which is only a minor revision away from the 3.4.3 installed on the `python` image.

Comment: Great, thanks for the informative reply. I had to add some commands to the Dockerfile (apt-getting python3-pip) but it all works now.